# CSS background doesn't repeat on stock android browser?

Tags: android, html, css, svg, android-browser

Code is very simple, as follows:

```
#intro-panel .button.loading {
    background-image: url(../img/loading_button.svg);
    background-size: auto 103%;
}
```

Chrome 36:

[image]

Same goes for Chrome on android 4.2.2

However, the stock browser serves me this cryptically broken piece of crap (disregard the font):

[image]

I've tried explicitly enabling background-repeat as well as slapping on a 3d transform to see if hardware rendering could solve it. No luck. 
What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
background: url("img/loading_button.svg") 
repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

(may work if your trying to repeat horizontally)

Also, I think Android struggles rendering svg images, maybe try a png instead.

Comment: Sorry, same outcome unfortunately... I will use PNG or CSS gradient solution as last resort.

Comment: I read an article stating use png not svg for android so it may work. Let me know the solution if you find it

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, seems that old android browsers dont like to repeat SVGs in any direction. when i switched to PNG everything worked as expected.